# Create new dataframe column based on 2 criteria from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['JOHN','ALLEN','BOB','NIKI','CHARLIE','CHANG'],
              'Age':[35,42,63,29,47,51],
              'Salary_in_1000':[100,93,78,120,64,115],
             'FT_Team':['STEELERS','SEAHAWKS','FALCONS','FALCONS','PATRIOTS','STEELERS']})
```

df output:

```
-   Name    Age Salary_in_1000  FT_Team
0   JOHN    35  100 STEELERS
1   ALLEN   42  93  SEAHAWKS
2   BOB 63  78  FALCONS
3   NIKI    29  120 FALCONS
4   CHARLIE 47  64  PATRIOTS
5   CHANG   51  115 STEELERS
```

And my dataframe that I am trying to complete:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['JOHN','ALLEN','BOB','NIKI','CHARLIE','CHANG'],
                  'Age':[35,42,63,29,47,51],})
```

df1 output:

```
  - Name    Age 
    0   JOHN    35  
    1   ALLEN   42  
    2   BOB 63  78  
    3   NIKI    29  
    4   CHARLIE 47  
    5   CHANG   51
```

I would like to add a new column to `df1` that references `['FT_Team']` from `df` based upon `'Name'` and `'Age'` in `df1`.

I believe that the new code should look something like a .map; however, I am completely stumped as to what the arguments would be for multiple arguments.

```
df1['FT_Team] =
```

final output:

```
 -  Name    Age FT_Team
    0   JOHN    35  STEELERS
    1   ALLEN   42  SEAHAWKS
    2   BOB 63  FALCONS
    3   NIKI    29  FALCONS
    4   CHARLIE 47  PATRIOTS
    5   CHANG   51  STEELERS
```

Ultimately, I would like to match the football team from `df` based upon Name AND Age in `df1`

Comment: `df1=df1.merge(df[['Name','Age','FT_Team']], on=['Name','Age'], how='left')`?

Comment: That works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Quang Hoang:

```
df1=df1.merge(df[['Name','Age','FT_Team']], on=['Name','Age'], how='left')
```